# Code Dependency documentation software

Tags: c++, c

I am looking for a tool to document legacy source code for an embedded C project I work with.  I had it in my mind that there was a tool that would create charts of the various C and .h files, but I can't recall what it is called.  Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big list at [this url](http://grok2.tripod.com/code_comprehension.html) too.

Answer (score 6):

[CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) The NDepend like for C\C++

Answer (score 5):

[doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/)

If you also install [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), then [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) can generate nice [call graphs](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~peterchd/doxygen/) and other [diagrams](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/diagrams.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

[Understand](http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/)